# Boot stalls when turning on the power

Tags: display

I got a Raspberry 3 model B and connected it with a keyboard, a mouse.Also, I connected the RPi with an HDMI-DVI converter to my Planar monitor, it's fine at the beginning of turning on the RPi. However, my boot stalls after some time, like the picture showing here.[image]

I searched on the Internet and tried to modify the code in config.txt.

Uncomment the line hdmi_force_hotplug=1

Uncomment the line hdmi_group=2

Uncomment the line hdmi_mode=16

Uncomment the line hdmi_drive=1
But it doesn't work. I deal with this problem the whole day but still not figure it out. I hope you can help me!

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: If you need only a general purpose OS, try installing the official Raspbian Jessie. Download [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/). NOOBS is the easiest way to install it

Comment: You appear to be using some proprietary (adafruit) OS. The rest of your screen shot is illegible. Try a standard OS. You obviously have a display output so fiddling with the settings isn't going to fix whatever problem you have.

Comment: Thanks! We use Linux OS. Is the problem of booting? But I can successfully boot by connecting to a touchscreen.

Comment: Actually, it's totally what I see from the screen. The last 3 lines are some values of fbtft.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry for that things. Because I found that I don't need a touchscreen, so I re-claim my question.

Comment: I did not notice this in your last question, but from the screenshot, you are running occidentalis a modified raspbian from adafruit. That would lead me to believe that you may also have their tft touchscreen (you can confirm this as their tft will have their logo and or name on it somewhere (as in the pic here https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-3-dot-5-touch-screen-for-raspberry-pi/overview) not a waveshare.

Comment: if it is an adafruit tft it may just be simpler to burn a new SD card as I mentioned in my answer.  But, there is a mrthod on this page to frce HDMI outout https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-3-dot-5-touch-screen-for-raspberry-pi/faq

Comment: @Milliways good catch I missed the adafruit logo for occidentalis, which means he may be running a pitft not a waveshare - thanks.

Comment: Holly Thanks!!! It works!!! My touchscreen is adafruit 3.5in. It's on Jessie Pi installs. Thanks!!